# How to fetch table data from azure SQL database using web app service in ios?

Tags: ios, asp.net, sql-server, swift, azure

I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-ios-get-started) document to connect iOS (Swift) app to Azure, this is my code to connect database to my app:

```
let client = MSClient(applicationURLString: "https://<webappname>.azurewebsites.net")
        let table = client.table(withName: "User")
        table.read(completion:  { (items, error) in
            print(String(describing: error))
        })
```

and when I run the app, azure gives below response:

> UserInfo={com.Microsoft.MicrosoftAzureMobile.ErrorResponseKey= { URL:
>   https://.webappname.azurewebsites.net/tables/User } { Status Code: 404, Headers {
>   "Content-Length" = ( 0 ); Date = ( "Mon, 16 Sep 2019 06:01:42 GMT" );
>   Server = ( Kestrel ); "Set-Cookie" = (
>   "ARRAffinity=9d50440330c6da9f063baa60c470baaccbb1dd7c2e349666c42c6bd54274ea59;Path=/;HttpOnly;Domain=.azurewebsites.net"
>   ); "X-Powered-By" = ( "ASP.NET" ); } }, NSLocalizedDescription=,
>   com.Microsoft.MicrosoftAzureMobile.ErrorRequestKey= { URL:
>   https://.webappname.azurewebsites.net/tables/User }})

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Well the error is pretty clear, your url is wrong, [HTTP 404](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes, but I have 'User' table in the .NET backend, I don't understand where is a problem with azure SQL database connection

Comment: Look at the url after //, it is lacking your specific part and starts with .azurewebsites.net. It should be something like mySite.azurewebsites.net

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks for your point. i update my question